# Arcgis desktop connection to oracle

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, oracle-dbms

I am trying to create a database connection from ArcGIS desktop 10.1 to SDE Geodatabase on Oracle server with direct connection using Oracle easy connect syntax
So, from ArcCatalog I use "Add database connection"
then I chose Oracle in database platform

then in the instance I write down

myserver: port/serviceid

so I write

dbserer:1539/devDatabase

but it gives me ora-12154 TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier

I thought by using the easy connect I don't have to worry about TNS names

Comment: Do you have ArcSDE?

Comment: Yes, I am connecting to ArcSDE
I will re-write my question

Comment: Assuming your are on Windows (64bit?) http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002n00000038000000

Comment: Did you match the case of the service identifier as created?

Comment: I ended up uninstall oracle client and install it again.
and it is working now.
I am not sure what was the cause of the problem, but I am highly suspecting it is a bug in ArcGIS desktop 10.1 connection.